# Build Time Series of Natural Gas Forward Price Strips with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with a time series of historical natural gas forward curves.  IE on each date in the past, i have a monthly price for natural gas for the following 17 months.  I have these prices for two different locations.  So each date has 34 rows of data (2 locs x 17 months).

Natural gas is sometimes bought and sold as seasonal strips.  The winter strip is November to March (5 months).  The summer strip is April to October (seven months).  I would like to average the prices of the individual months in the data frame as strips - for each historical date, and for each location.

Here is some sample data:

```
Location    Month   Date    Price
a   11/1/2017   11/1/2017   1
a   12/1/2017   11/1/2017   1
a   1/1/2018    11/1/2017   1
a   2/1/2018    11/1/2017   1
a   3/1/2018    11/1/2017   1
a   4/1/2018    11/1/2017   2
a   5/1/2018    11/1/2017   2
a   6/1/2018    11/1/2017   2
a   7/1/2018    11/1/2017   2
a   8/1/2018    11/1/2017   2
a   9/1/2018    11/1/2017   2
a   10/1/2018   11/1/2017   2
a   11/1/2018   11/1/2017   3
a   12/1/2018   11/1/2017   3
a   1/1/2019    11/1/2017   3
a   2/1/2019    11/1/2017   3
a   3/1/2019    11/1/2017   3
b   11/1/2017   11/1/2017   4
b   12/1/2017   11/1/2017   4
b   1/1/2018    11/1/2017   4
b   2/1/2018    11/1/2017   4
b   3/1/2018    11/1/2017   4
b   4/1/2018    11/1/2017   5
b   5/1/2018    11/1/2017   5
b   6/1/2018    11/1/2017   5
b   7/1/2018    11/1/2017   5
b   8/1/2018    11/1/2017   5
b   9/1/2018    11/1/2017   5
b   10/1/2018   11/1/2017   5
b   11/1/2018   11/1/2017   6
b   12/1/2018   11/1/2017   6
b   1/1/2019    11/1/2017   6
b   2/1/2019    11/1/2017   6
b   3/1/2019    11/1/2017   6
a   11/1/2017   11/2/2017   7
a   12/1/2017   11/2/2017   7
a   1/1/2018    11/2/2017   7
a   2/1/2018    11/2/2017   7
a   3/1/2018    11/2/2017   7
a   4/1/2018    11/2/2017   8
a   5/1/2018    11/2/2017   8
a   6/1/2018    11/2/2017   8
a   7/1/2018    11/2/2017   8
a   8/1/2018    11/2/2017   8
a   9/1/2018    11/2/2017   8
a   10/1/2018   11/2/2017   8
a   11/1/2018   11/2/2017   9
a   12/1/2018   11/2/2017   9
a   1/1/2019    11/2/2017   9
a   2/1/2019    11/2/2017   9
a   3/1/2019    11/2/2017   9
b   11/1/2017   11/2/2017   10
b   12/1/2017   11/2/2017   10
b   1/1/2018    11/2/2017   10
b   2/1/2018    11/2/2017   10
b   3/1/2018    11/2/2017   10
b   4/1/2018    11/2/2017   11
b   5/1/2018    11/2/2017   11
b   6/1/2018    11/2/2017   11
b   7/1/2018    11/2/2017   11
b   8/1/2018    11/2/2017   11
b   9/1/2018    11/2/2017   11
b   10/1/2018   11/2/2017   11
b   11/1/2018   11/2/2017   12
b   12/1/2018   11/2/2017   12
b   1/1/2019    11/2/2017   12
b   2/1/2019    11/2/2017   12
b   3/1/2019    11/2/2017   12
```

The seventeen forward months in this data are equivalent to three seasonal strips (two winters and one summer).  So after this data is averaged, there would be three seasonal strip prices, for two locations, for two historical dates.  I've used simple ascending prices in each season to keep the numbers simple.  I will also need to rename the forward months to the strip names.  We'll use JV for the summer and XH for the winter, with a corresponding year - so our example will be XH1718, JV18, XH1819, for winter starting in 17 ending in 18, summer of 18, winter starting in 18 ending in 19.

The average prices for the strips with the new names would look something like this:

```
Loc        A          A       A       B      B         B
Season    XH1718    JV18    XH1819  XH1718  JV18    XH1819
11/1/2017   1         2        3       4      5        6
11/2/2017   7         8        9       10     11       12
```

Unfortunately I don't have any code for this.  I feel like it might be possible to average the strips while pivoting this data frame, but i'm just not sure how to tell python to average everything in the seasonal month ranges (this is the real key - I think for the rest I would group by), for each historical day, for each location.

The format of the output is not very important, it could just be a dataframe with the new average strips, or could be a pivot table.

In a nutshell I'm trying to:

-Build average prices for each historical day in the "Date" column (there are two in the sample data)

-Build average prices for each location (there are two in the sample data)

-Average the prices using dates in the "Month" column of the data (there are 17 months, but three seasons - two winters at five months each, one summer at seven months)

-Rename the new average prices XH1718, JV18, XH1819.  If there were a way to do this in a formulaic fashion, that would be even better

Thanks for any suggestions or help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do what you want by just creating your season label and then using `pd.pivot_table()` with the mean for the aggregation function.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

conds = [df.Month.dt.month<=3, df.Month.dt.month.between(4,10), df.Month.dt.month > 10]
choices = [(df.Month.dt.year-1).astype(str).str[2:] + df.Month.dt.year.astype(str).str[2:],
           df.Month.dt.year.astype(str).str[2:],
           (df.Month.dt.year).astype(str).str[2:] + (df.Month.dt.year+1).astype(str).str[2:]]

df['syear'] = np.select(conds, choices)
df['Season'] =  df.Month.dt.month.between(4,10).map({False: 'XH', True: 'JV'}) + df.syear
```

At this point, `df` looks like:

```
print(df.head(7))
#  Location      Month       Date  Price syear  Season
#0        a 2017-11-01  11/1/2017      1  1718  XH1718
#1        a 2017-12-01  11/1/2017      1  1718  XH1718
#2        a 2018-01-01  11/1/2017      1  1718  XH1718
#3        a 2018-02-01  11/1/2017      1  1718  XH1718
#4        a 2018-03-01  11/1/2017      1  1718  XH1718
#5        a 2018-04-01  11/1/2017      2    18    JV18
#6        a 2018-05-01  11/1/2017      2    18    JV18
```

Now just `pivot_table` to get your desired output.

```
df2 = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['Date'], columns=['Location', 'Season'], 
                     values='Price', aggfunc='mean')
df2.index.name=None
```

`df2` is now:

```
Location     a                  b              
Season    JV18 XH1718 XH1819 JV18 XH1718 XH1819
11/1/2017    2      1      3    5      4      6
11/2/2017    8      7      9   11     10     12
```

Comment: Thanks @ALollz, this is a great answer that works well.  Is building new required data into the df and then pivoting standard practice? This seems to be a standard practice I see in a lot of answers here on SO. I thought perhaps pandas might calculate the date range while calculating averages - IE if pandas new only the start and end dates (for cases they were not standard seasonal strips as above) it might pass the date range to average based on some type of .between functionality like you used above.  Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Also, if you were subtracting location a from b, would it be better to do before or after the above work?  And what if you want to specify which location to subtract from which?

Comment: @thesimplevoodoo There are a lot of built in functions for pandas to group data based on dates. But at the end, it really all comes down to built in functionality that allows you to easily create some grouping 'key' for each group. So for instance, if you have a list of datetimes, you can use the `.dt.month` attributes to easily label every date by it's month. The issue here was that the groupings weren't really standard. One was 5 months, the other was 7, and they spanned calendar years.

Comment: You could probably use something like `pd.IntervalIndex` or `pd.Grouper` but that logic above essentially does the same job. I would say it's probably easier to just do the subtraction afterwards. In the pivot table format you have the averages and they're already grouped by season and the `Date` so it's not too difficult to do. You could also just use a `groupby` if you didn't want to deal with the pivot table format.

Comment: thanks, those are all good points.  In this case I wondered if a good option might be to calculate the number of days between the dates, and then take the mean of any dates in the df, in that trailing x number of days.  Perhaps pandas is not built to calculate quickly in that fashion.  Thanks again for your response

Comment: I have suddenly been getting an "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame" error here (from area where you set conds and choices, and then add columns). I believe this suggests the filter is creating multiple copies of the DF.  Any idea what line might be causing this?  Is this a false positive?